# Процесс загузки данных в DataGrid занимает длительное время

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

Столкнулся с проблемой в **WPF**: На одном из `View` размещён `DataGrid`.
Метод, в котором производится загрузка данных выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
public async void LoadProductsToDataGrid()
{
    var productsListFromDAL = await context.GetItemsAsync(p => p.Manufacturer);
    //загрузка данных ObservableCollection, привязанной к DataGrid
    productsListFromDAL.ToList().ForEach(p => ProductsObservableCollection.Add(new ProductModel(p)));
}
```

Всё работает замечательно, но лишь до тех пор, пока количество возвращаемых из **DAL** объектов типа `Product` не достигает пары тысяч. Тогда загрузка длится ОООЧЕНЬ долго, интерфейс затормаживается. Подскажите, как правильно поступать в такой ситуации? Может, данные следует подгружать динамически? Или использовать другой контрол. Или же проблема в том, что я каждый *EF-объект* оборачиваю в объект **MVVM**?

Comment: Тормозит - профилируйте. Я бы попробовал добавить `ObservableCollection` метод `AddRange`, потому что в текущем виде грид может пытаться среагировать на добавление каждой записи, а должен - один раз на всю пачку.

Comment: Посмотрите, что конкретно тормозит - загрузка из context или при манипуляциях ToList  и foreach?